# Migrate Nexus repository Data

Tags: openshift, nexus3, persistent-volumes

We are upgrading Openshift Cluster from 3.6 to version 3.11.

What is the best strategy to be followed to move the nexus repository data from version 3.6 to Openshift cluster 3.11. The data is stored in persistent volumes